# Обновить значение поля в массиве объектов с помощью useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть некоторый массив объектов с id и названиями колонок

```
const cols = [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: "TODO"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      title: "InProgress"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: "Testing"
    }, {
      id: 3,
      title: "Done"
    },
  ]
```

Есть state в который он записывается

```
  const [colArray, setColArray] = useState(cols);
```

Я хочу найти определенный объект по id и записать в поле title новое значение. Подскажите как это сделать?

Я пытался сделать так, но получаю ошибку несовпадения типов.

```
 const EditColName = () => {
    setColArray(prevState => [...prevState, colArray.filter(item => item.id === editColId)])
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const EditColName = () => {
  setColArray(prevState => 
    prevState.map(item => 
      item.id === editColId 
        ? { ...item, title: newTitle }
        : item
    )
  )
}
```

Предполагается, что `editColId` и `newTitle` определены где-то снаружи.

Comment: Красивое и лаконичное решение. Пожалуй, и себе на заметку возьму.

Answer (score 0):

На TS не пишу, но в целом логика такая: нужно в state записать новый массив, в которой скопировать все элементы без именений и добавить новый, уже изменённый.

```
const EditColName = newObj => {
    setColArray([...colArray.filter(item => item.id !== newObj.id), newObj])
}
```

Если критически важен порядок элементов (не взирая на их id), то можно вместо фильтра использовать методы `slice` и `indexOf`, чтобы скопировать сначала всё, что до изменённого элемента, потом сам новый элемент, и всё, что после него.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что лучше сделать твой стейт таким:

```
const cols = {
  0: { title: "TODO", id: 0 },
  1: { title: "InProgress", id: 1 },
  2: { title: "Testing", id: 2 },
  3: { title: "Done", id: 3 },
};
```

И тогда тебе будет легко с ним работать

```
setColArray({ ...cols, [id]: { id, title: "newTitle" } });
```

Comment: Надо отвечать на русском языке.